# How to reduce toilet tank refill noise?

Tags: toilet, noise

The refill tube that goes from the valve into the overflow tube in my toilet tank sprays water with quite a bit of pressure and makes a lot of noise when the tank refills. It's attached with a clip and an angle adapter.

Is there any other adapter or maybe other type of (wider?) refill tube that I can use for this and reduce the noise?

This is one of those old style toilets with the tank hanging higher up close to the ceiling. The overflow tube is metallic which only contributes to the problem.

Comment: Hm. Seems like kludging on an aerator would be a dandy solution, but I think it would have to be a kludge, as I've never seen such a thing for the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try partially closing the water supply shutoff valve to the water tank unit. This would reduce pressure and flow rate some and thus could also reduce the noise produced in tank.

If you do decide on this approach make sure to test it out a number of times to make sure that the flush operation and the refill time are suitable.

Comment: Half closed valves can sometimes be quite noisy themselves.

Comment: I agree that the valve can cause noise but I said the OP "could try" it. There is the possibly that the filling water tank acts like a sound reverberation chamber and makes the sound louder. I have a quite noisy toilet too but the noise level tapers off a lot as the tank fills to the point that it is almost unnoticeable just before the float valve shuts things off.

Comment: I tried closing the valve, but (as it was pointed out) then there is more noise from the valve.

Not sure if there's much more that can be done without replacing the existing (metallic/copper/brass?) overflow pipe assembly with something new made out of plastic.